# prevent output from script in xinetd service

Tags: bash, xinetd

I have a bash script that starts Xvnc after doing some other processing, and it's launched from a xinetd service. However the script indirectly outputs some text to stdout and stderr, which gets sent back to the connecting client.

Is there some way to tell xinetd to ignore any ouput from the script and just let Xvnc take over the connection?

(I assume Xvnc somehow takes over the socket from xinetd, rather than just using stdout to communicate with xinetd?)

Answer (score 0):

Put the following lines into the script at the beginning:

```
exec >/dev/null
exec 2>/dev/null
```